# DynamoDB Query Iterator

Tags: php, laravel, promise, amazon-dynamodb

Based on official DynamoDB documentation, any query operation will retrieve up to a maximum of 1MB of data, and it is recommended to use the getIterator method to retrieve the entire list of data matching the query. The sample code provided on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-dynamodb.html#query as below.

```
$iterator = $client->getIterator('Query', array(
    'TableName'     => 'errors',
    'KeyConditions' => array(
        'id' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array('N' => '1201')
            ),
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
        ),
        'time' => array(
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array('N' => strtotime("-15 minutes"))
            ),
            'ComparisonOperator' => 'GT'
        )
    )
));

// Each item will contain the attributes we added
foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    // Grab the time number value
    echo $item['time']['N'] . "\n";
    // Grab the error string value
    echo $item['error']['S'] . "\n";
}
```

However, I would like to collate the results in one json object and return it as a response after the iterations have completed. I attempted to use a try block over the foreach loop as in the code below. But there's an error message that says "localhost is currently unable to handle this request" with an error code of 500.

Is there anything wrong with the way I'm handling the promises (are they considered promises?)? Or its purely because the dataset is too large and the connection timed out? I deliberately commented out the connect_timeout parameter when I instantiated the DynamoDbClient but it still doesn't allow me to fetch more data... Any advice on how I can get around this?

```
$results = array();
try {
    foreach($iterator as $item){
        array_push($results, $item);
    }
    return response()->json($results);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    return response()->json($e);
}
```

Comment: you can try this code for only one iteration, and do break then see the results

Comment: @MohammadAlabed good idea, but it didn't quite yield the result I expected. I did a dd($result) in the foreach loop to see what I will get after 1 iteration, and there was only one record instead of the first batch of 1MB of data :(